How to get the iterator of the ancestor nodes during DFS or BFS?
I am able to solve this by myself, but somebody may already know the answer, so saving manpower, instead of me probably trying several variants.
What is an easy way during either DFS or BFS of a DAG to get a (reversely) topologically sorted list (or better iterator) of all traversed "as an ancestor" of the current node ancestor nodes of the current node?
By "as an ancestor" I mean appearing in the path of parent node -> child node as the natural relationship in DFS or BFS traversal order.
In other words, I need the iterator that returns me to the root node of the search by the same (reversed) way as I got to the current node.
I have access to both DFS and BFS algorithms in the form of iterators. I also have DFS-post-order and BFS-post-order. Can we use this to simplify my task?

A bigger problem that I am solving is to transform a DAG to a sub-DAG with some nodes (as specified by a known predicate) eliminated transforming paths A0->...->An into A0->An, if nodes between A0 and An are eliminated.

Oh, the easiest way to solve this seems to use recursion.
